# Image not displaying with random

Tags: java, processing

I am currently coding a flappy bird clone inside Processing(java). Whenever the code down below executes nothing shows on the screen.

```
void display()
{
  float birdPick = random(0, 1);

  if (birdPick == 0)
  {
    image(yellowBird, x, y, 80, 80);
  }

  if (birdPick == 1)
  {
    image(blueBird, x, y, 80, 80);
  }
}
```

Comment: `birdPick ` is a float, but `0` and `1` are Integers - comparision will fail.  What type of variable does `random` return ?

Comment: Also, what is `random`? Is it a custom method?

Comment: Also what does image() do and how do we know that you've addressed potential threading issue with graphics? No where near enough code to give a definite answer.

Comment: random() is a built in processing method taking a random number from 0-given number, it returns a float

Comment: @ScaryWombat.Please notice that this is a [tag:processing] question. The `random()` function returns a `float`. Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java) for more info.

Comment: @AndrewL Please notice that this is a [tag:processing] question. The `random()` function returns a `float`. Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java) for more info.

Comment: @John3136 Please notice that this is a [tag:processing] question. The `image()` function simply draws an image on the rendering thread. Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `random(0, 1)` returns a `float` between `0` and `1`.

In other words, these numbers will be things like `.01` or `.333`. It will almost never be exactly `0`, and it will never be exactly `1` (the second number is not included).

If you want the `if` statement to evaluate to `true` 50% of the time, then you can check if the value is less than `.5`, since half the values will be below that and half the values will be above that.

```
 float birdPick = random(0, 1);
 if (birdPick < .5){
   image(yellowBird, x, y, 80, 80);
 }
 else{
   image(blueBird, x, y, 80, 80);
 }
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html)

Comment: Which does make it slightly more likely to move the blue bird, since the number of values is slightly bigger. To fix, the second if should be `else if (birdPick > .5) {` - and do nothing if birdPick equals 0.5

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In reality that difference is not noticeable at all, so I really wouldn't worry about it. If it's really a concern, then doing nothing is probably not the way to go.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Actually, thinking about it now, are you sure the blue bird is more likely? I think they're equally likely, since `0-.49999` == `.5-.99999`, right?

Comment: Thinking about it more, it depends on the API that we don't know. I take `random(0,1)` to return a number between 0 and 1 (both ends inclusive) but I can see 3 other options.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt We do know the API. It's the [tag:processing] language. The `0` is included, but the `1` is not. Both sides are equal.

Comment: @KevinWorkman thanks a lot, I assumed that **random(0,1)** returned either 0 or 1. Not 0-1, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @KevinWorkman new problem, now whenever I call the `display()` method in the `draw()` method, it continuously switches between blue and yellow.

Comment: @Sterv That's because the `draw()` function is being called 60 times per second. If you want to stick with blue or yellow the entire time, then you need to decide that once at the beginning of the sketch instead of every frame. The `setup()` function is good for stuff like that.